# Bash Scripting in Linux Variable/Array Assignment

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to make my shell script similar to ordering at a fast food restaurant.
However, I'm confused as to how to set arrays to determine the size of the drink the customer wishes to order. My sizes are as follows:

```
small=12oz
medium=16oz
large=20oz
xlarge =24oz
```

I have my shell script programmed to read the customers input for $size but I don't know how to translate the word "small" into an oz amount when customer declares their size. I as going to use the `eval`“$size="` option but what do I put so that it can vary? Will x be sufficient?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use variable indirection (retrieve the value of the variable whose name is specified as the value of $size), but a better practice would be to use associative arrays, which you will find explained [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try an associative lookup.

```
$: declare -A drink=(
    [small]=12oz
    [medium]=16oz
    [large]=20oz
   )
$: choice=medium
$: echo "${drink[$choice]}"
16oz
$: drink[xlg]=32oz
$: choice=xlg
$: echo "${drink[$choice]}"
32oz
```

Watch the syntax, though, it's kind of a pain.

Comment: You need to declare `size` as an associative array first, or it defaults to being an indexed array. Notice in your example that `${size[$choice]}` outputs 20oz, not 16oz as would be expected, because each of your assignments sets (and resets) `size[0]` as the strings are evaluated as variable names in the arithmetic contexts.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having difficulty understanding the concepts of arrays. I understand how to set but I was confused on how to get it called back into my program. I'm just learning how to script and there's a lot of ways to get the job done!